# Cant implement conditional code inside playwright's page object model

Tags: javascript, typescript, playwright, playwright-test

I'm trying to implement conditional code in playwright inside of page object. It depends on if element is found on page or not. The problem is - returned value is always the same, no matter if element is present or not. Here is my code:

```
    this.pagePlaceholder = page.locator('.s-wrapper.s-wrapper_placeholder');


  async clearUpPage() {
    const placeholdersNumber = await this.pagePlaceholder.count();
    console.log(placeholdersNumber);

      
        if (placeholdersNumber < 1) {
          await this.mainSection.hover({
            position: {
              x: 200,
              y: 150,
            },
          });
    
          await this.page.click('.section-options__btn._del:visible');
          await expect(this.pagePlaceholder).toBeVisible();
        }
      }
```

So the problem is - count() always returns 0, even if element of that class is present on that page. I also tried solutions with "if (this.pagePlaceholder)" and "if (this.pagePlaceholder.isVisible())" and those also return same value no matter what. If I use 'waitForSelector" inside "if" - it throws timeout error if selector is not found, so test is failed instead of case being skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to find a solution on Playwright's github. The solution is - to use separate "delay" function like that:

```
import { delay } from './utils';

 async clearUpPage() {
    await delay(5000, null);

    const placeholdersNumber = await this.pagePlaceholder.count();
    console.log(placeholdersNumber);

    if (placeholdersNumber < 1) {...}
}
```

delay() function is imported from the file utils.ts:

```
export function delay<T>(milliseconds: number, value: T): Promise<T> {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) { 
        setTimeout(resolve.bind(null, value), milliseconds)
    });
}
```

[Original answer](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/9224#issuecomment-1070329934)

Note that milliseconds value matters. Value from original answer (2000) didn't help in my case.

Comment: Playwright provides a page.waitForTimeout() function that can be used for waiting.

Comment: @Greener that also works. Thanks! Too bad that more elegant approach doesn't work. As tests with "timeout" are flaky :(

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a

```js
await this.pagePlaceholder.waitFor({ state: "visible" });
```

Before you perform the count, I suspect that the screen is still loading when you try to count it (its not there).

Failing that you might want to enable trace recording and look at that!.

Comment: It solves the counting problem. But it throws error if element can't be found on the page - (locator.waitFor: Timeout 20000ms exceeded. 
--waiting for selector ".s-wrapper.s-wrapper_placeholder" to be visible). And I already tried to use it inside if () check, but playwright doesn't allow that.

Comment: Is "pagePlaceholder"  always shown on the page or is it optional?

Comment: It's optional. Thats why I need to use "if" statement :)

Comment: const shown = await this.pagePlaceholder.isVisible({timeout: 20000});

Will let you see if its currently shown or not

Comment: Not sure why, but as I stated in original post - it always returns same value (false in this case, and true for "isHidden"), even if element is clearly visible. I tried to await for "this.page.waitForLoadState()" before running your code - same results.